# warning about security/enforce-explicit-visibility: No visibility specified explicitly for multiply function

Tags: solidity, solc

my ide is vs(can find solc version is 0.4.17),but my solcjs is 0.4.24.when I run this simple code

```
`pragma solidity^ 0.4.45;
contract test{
    function multiply(uint a) constant returns(uint d){
        return a*7;
    }
}
```

there is warning "security/enforce-explicit-visibility: No visibility specified explicitly for multiply function."

When I run another simple code a warning come with "[solc] Function state mutability can be restricted to pure".

Is there some wrong with version conflict about solc/solcjs? How I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The first warning is saying that you forgot to mark the visibility (public, private, external or internal) of your function.

The second means that your function can be marked as `pure`, which means that it does not read or write from the blockchain. `constant` or `view` functions are allowed to read from the blockchain, but yours doesn't.

See the [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#functions) for more specifics

This should elimintae some warnings:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract test{
    function multiply(uint a) public pure returns(uint d){
        return a*7;
    }
}
```